# Optimizing COUNT() on MariaDB for a Statistics Table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, perl, mariadb

I've read a number of posts here and elsewhere about people wrestling to improve the performance of the MySQL/MariaDB `COUNT`function, but I haven't found a solution that quite fits what I am trying to do. I'm trying to produce a live updating list of read counts for a list of articles. Each time a visitor visits a page, a log table in the SQL database records the usual access log-type data (IP, browser, etc.). Of particular interest, I record the user's ID (uid) and I process the user agent tag to classify known spiders (uaType). The article itself is identified by the "paid" column. The goal is to produce a statistic that doesn't count the poster's own views of the page and doesn't include known spiders, either.

Here's the query I have:

```
"COUNT(*) FROM uninet_log WHERE paid='1942' AND uid != '1' AND uaType != 'Spider'"
```

This works nicely enough, but very slowly (approximately 1 sec.) when querying against a database with 4.2 million log entries. If I run the query several times during a particular run, it increases the runtime by about another second for each query. I know I could group by `paid` and then run a single query, but even then (which would require some reworking of my code, but could be done) I feel like 1 second for the query is still really slow and I'm worried about the implications when the server is under a load.

I've tried switching out `COUNT(*)` for `COUNT(1)` or `COUNT(id)` but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I might create a better, faster query that would accomplish this same goal? I've thought about having a background process regularly calculate the statistics and cache them, but I'd love to stick to live updating information if possible.

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: Have and index on paid ?

Comment: general rule of thumb: any field used in a decision context, e.g. join, where, order by, should have an index on it. changing the exact thing you're counting is mostly irrelevant - you're counting a subset of the total records, meaning the db has to scan for your `where` clause matches.

Comment: Thank you both. I had the index on the wrong field, it seems. This made a huge difference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a boolean "summarized" column to your statistics table and making it part of a multicolumn index with `paid`.

Then have a background process that produces/updates rows containing the read count in a summary table (by article) and marks the statistics table rows as summarized.  (Though the summary table could just be your article table.)

Then your live query reports the sum of the already summarized results and the as-yet-unsummarized statistics rows.

This also allows you to expire old statistics table rows without losing your read counts.

(All this assumes you already have an index on `paid`; if you don't, definitely add one and that will likely solve your problem for now, though in the long run likely you still want to be able to delete old statistics records.)

Comment: Wow, thanks -- that's a fantastic plan. I really appreciate the suggestions. I didn't have an index on paid, just on id, which now that I think about it wasn't nearly as helpful. The idea you suggest regarding dealing with the rows long term makes perfect sense; I'm going to implement that tonight. Thanks again!

Comment: Better yet, don't add that `summarized` column.  Instead, keep track of where you left off in the table.  Quite possibly the `id` would work.  (Put that in another table, perhaps a trivial one-row, one-column table.)  Otherwise, the `UPDATE ... SET summarized=1` will become your worst bottleneck.